# After computer upgrade, local is modified before git init, now want to sync with upstream

Tags: git

I recently upgraded my computer (Windows 10) and copied working files from the old hard disk to the new one. *Without the hidden .git folders copied*. I started to work on my new system and then thought "ok, it's now time to push". But then I realized haven't `git init` the local working folder, and now want to push to upstream.

If I `git init` my local and then pull (fetch?) from upstream, surely I will lose my current work right?

I could just move my current work to other directory first, pull files from upstream to that now-empty dir, then copy back my working files to that dir, then push to upstream. But it seems to me there must be a better way.

I have several projects (some are modified, some are not) with the same state (no git yet). And now want to safely sync all with upstream.

Any suggestions?

Also, what is the best way (pertaining to git workflow) to manage computer/hard disk upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

To be sure, I would:

- rename (not copy) my current folder to new name
- clone the repository to the old current folder
- import my changes

That is:

```
cd /path/to/cloned/repo
git --work-tree=../newName add .
git commit -m "my new work"
git push
```

That way, there is no risk of you loosing your work in progress in your current folder.